# How can I fix NPM

Tags: node.js, npm

If I try to install a package this is the error

```
npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2021-04-22T16_39_41_735Z-debug.log
```

And the File content is:

```
0 verbose cli [ '/usr/bin/node', '/usr/bin/npm', 'i', 'htop' ]
1 info using npm@7.7.6
2 info using node@v15.14.0
3 timing npm:load:whichnode Completed in 1ms
4 timing config:load:defaults Completed in 1ms
5 timing config:load:file:/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/npmrc Completed in 0ms
6 timing config:load:builtin Completed in 1ms
7 timing config:load:cli Completed in 2ms
8 timing config:load:env Completed in 0ms
9 timing config:load:file:/.npmrc Completed in 0ms
10 timing config:load:project Completed in 1ms
11 timing config:load:file:/root/.npmrc Completed in 0ms
12 timing config:load:user Completed in 0ms
13 timing config:load:file:/usr/etc/npmrc Completed in 0ms
14 timing config:load:global Completed in 0ms
15 timing config:load:validate Completed in 1ms
16 timing config:load:setEnvs Completed in 0ms
17 timing config:load Completed in 6ms
18 timing npm:load:configload Completed in 6ms
19 timing npm:load:setTitle Completed in 0ms
20 timing npm:load:setupLog Completed in 1ms
21 timing npm:load:cleanupLog Completed in 2ms
22 timing npm:load:configScope Completed in 0ms
23 timing npm:load:projectScope Completed in 0ms
24 timing npm:load Completed in 13ms
25 timing config:load:flatten Completed in 3ms
26 timing arborist:ctor Completed in 1ms
27 timing idealTree:init Completed in 225ms
28 timing idealTree:userRequests Completed in 1ms
29 silly idealTree buildDeps
30 timing idealTree Completed in 228ms
31 timing command:install Completed in 238ms
32 verbose stack Error: Tracker "idealTree" already exists
32 verbose stack     at Arborist.[_onError] (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/@npmcli/arborist/lib/tracker.js:101:11)
32 verbose stack     at Arborist.addTracker (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/@npmcli/arborist/lib/tracker.js:28:21)
32 verbose stack     at Arborist.[buildDeps] (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/@npmcli/arborist/lib/arborist/build-ideal-tree.js:692:10)
32 verbose stack     at Arborist.buildIdealTree (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/@npmcli/arborist/lib/arborist/build-ideal-tree.js:209:29)
32 verbose stack     at async Promise.all (index 1)
32 verbose stack     at async Arborist.reify (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/@npmcli/arborist/lib/arborist/reify.js:131:5)
32 verbose stack     at async Install.install (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/install.js:137:5)
33 verbose cwd /root
34 verbose Linux 4.19.0-16-amd64
35 verbose argv "/usr/bin/node" "/usr/bin/npm" "i" "htop"
36 verbose node v15.14.0
37 verbose npm  v7.7.6
38 error Tracker "idealTree" already exists
39 verbose exit 1
```

Comment: What do I have to do to reproduce this problem?

Comment: I dont know I just installed Nodejs with:
$ curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_15.x | sudo bash -
$ sudo apt install nodejs
$ node -v

Comment: Som you followed the above link to install the Node.js?

Comment: So I used it to install nodejs

Comment: @Apoorva Chikara ?

Comment: Try following [this](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-node-js-on-debian-10) . Before running this check `npm -v ` if command o/p something remove the previous installation first. Try following one options only 'Installing the Official Debian Node.js Package'

Comment: now it says:
```Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 nodejs : Conflicts: npm
 npm : Depends: node-gyp (>= 3.6.2~) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Comment: btw the server is running webmin